# Term aggregation with shard_size

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

I have term query written like this, and I have 18 shards for my index. I have a question regarding the significance of shard-size parameter. higher shard-size parameter more accurate the query response,

```
{
  "terms": {
    "field": "@timestamp",
    "size": 1,
    "shard_size": 1000,
    "order": {
      "_count": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

even though I have only 18 shards, why is it expecting more values for shard_size, and in response giving proper response